# Let a and x be positive integers. Prove that if $x^2 \mid 2016$ and $2016 \mid a$, then gcd(a,x) = |x|

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Basically what I know so far is that $$x^2 \mid 2016$$ means there exists an integer q where $$2016 = qx^2$$

As well, $$2016 \mid a$$ means that there exist an integer r where $$a = r2016$$

I can substitute 2016 with $qx^2$ and that can yield $$a = r(qx^2) \implies a = (rq)x^2$$

And since rq is an integer I can conclude from what I've done so far that $$x^2 \mid a$$

Can someone help me on getting to the last part where I can show that gcd(a,x) = |x|?

Comment: You're basically there.  If $d$ is the largest number that divides $x$ but $x$ is negative, what value does $d$ have?

Comment: $x^2\,|\,a\implies x\,|\,a$.

Comment: $\color{#c00}x\cdot x\mid 2016\mid a\Rightarrow \color{#c00}x\mid a\,$ by the linked dupe.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I think this question is about the more subtle absolute value determination...

Comment: $gcd(a,x)\leq x$, $x$ positive.

Comment: @abiessu Please be patient - it takes time to populate the dupe list since SE only allows one dupe on initial closure. It then needs to be edited to add more.

Comment: @BillDubuque: ah, missed that second one, I wasn't aware more than one would show.  Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Why was this question upvoted? It seems awfully easy and straightforward. -1